# php delete element based on array of keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array and an array which holds the keys to a certain element in that multidimensional array. How can i unset that element, based on the array with keys. I am looking for code which can work regardless of the dimensions of the array.

Here is the example:

```
<?php
$array = array(
    1 => array('name' => 'mike','age' => 23),
    2 => array('name' => 'nick','age' => 18),
);

$keys   = array(2,'name');

//
//Here code to unset that element
//

/*
//This is how the new array should be:
$array = array(
    1 => array('name' => 'mike','age' => 23),
    2 => array('age' => 18),
);
*/
?>
```

Edit: The above code is for clearity. I can add what i have tried with unset() so far, but its not anything usefull and will make the question less clear. I am asking for a hint in the right direction, not fully working code.

Comment: It was merely a coding example to provide more explanation. I do not request that anybody write code for me, but i just added it like this so it is clear what i am looking for. All i need is someone to point me in the right direction, since i messed around with unset() but could not get anything usefull.

The most important thing when writing a question is making it clear, thats why i added code like this. Please be reasonable and delete your -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution:

```
<?php

function unsetByKeys($keys,&$array,$path = array()){

    $diff   = count($keys)-count($path);
    if($diff > 1){
        $path[] = $keys[count($path)];
        unsetByKeys($keys,$array,$path);
    }else{
        $lastKey    = $keys[count($path)];

        $subArray   = &$array;
        foreach($path AS $p){
            $subArray   = &$subArray[$p];
        }
        unset($subArray[$lastKey]);
    }
}

$array = array(
    1 => array('name' => 'mike','age' => 23),
    2 => array('name' => 'nick','age' => 18),
);

$keys   = array(2,'name');

unsetByKeys($keys,$array);

var_dump($array);
?>
```

Comment: Next time ask a correct question so i won't waste my time.

Answer (score -1):

**Code :**  (http://www.tehplayground.com/#9Oup7h6gh)

```
// example code

$array = array(
1 => array('name' => 'mike','age' => 23),
2 => array('name' => 'nick','age' => 18),
);

$keys   = array(2,'name');

unset($array[($keys[0])][($keys[1])]);

print_r($array);

/*
//This is how the new array should be:
$array = array(
    1 => array('name' => 'mike','age' => 23),
    2 => array('age' => 18),
);
*/
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => mike
        [age] => 23
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [age] => 18
    )

)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. This is what im looking for, but only then for a variable amount of keys. So the array might also have 3 levels (and the keys array 3 keys).

Basically i need to know how to get this: $array[($keys[0])][($keys[1])]
with a variable amount of keys.